# How to add an item based on a specific template when click on menu Add item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I want to create a template for example (Create a folder in the folder create 1 class and 1 interface with the names of the folder) and it will be created by right click on the project and in the menu, it will appear CreateTamplateClass

Can I do it using c# WinForms / Console Application and more .. ?

TNX

Comment: I tried to answer *How to create a Visual Studio multi-file Item Template having Folder with parameter replacement*, however the question in the current format is too broad. Please break it to a few other problems/questions like: • *How to create a multi-file item template?*, • *How to use parameter replacement for folders?*, • *How to add a menu item to right click menu of project/folder?*, • *How to add an item based on a specific template when click on menu item?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Visual Studio multi-file Item Template having Folder with parameter replacement

You can create a *C# Item Template* project or manually create the item template zip file yourself.

The item template zip file should contain the following files:

- *`Class.cs`*
- *`Interface.cs`*
- *`MyItemTemplate.vstemplate`*

Then you need to copy the zip file to following folder:

- *`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#`*

Then open a new instance of Visual Studio and create/open a C# project, then open *Add New Item* window and choose *MyItemTemplate* from *Visual C# Items* and assing a name like *MyItem1*, then the following structure will be created:

[image: Visual Studio multi-file Item Template having Folder]

Here is the content for template files in the zip file:

**Class.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace $rootnamespace$.$basename$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$: I$safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

**Interface.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace $rootnamespace$.$basename$
{
    interface $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

**MyItemTemplate.vstemplate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate-sdkextension/2010">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>MyItemTemplate</Name>
    <Description>My multi-file item template</Description>
    <Icon>MyItemTemplate.ico</Icon>
    <TemplateID>52ae3bdb-7fde-4d47-8a4b-d17d0c9269f7</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <DefaultName>MyItem.cs</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\I$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Interface.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
    <CustomParameters>
      <CustomParameter Name="$basename$" Value="$fileinputname$"/>
    </CustomParameters>    
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: Greate Thank you

Comment: when i creating that project it's unhappy with the $ sign : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1056 Unexpected character '$'

Comment: tried to install the latest compiler, .net framework, msbuild and still the same ..

Comment: Make sure you are using a Visual Studio Item Template project. Also make sure the Build Action of .cs files is `None` (in properties window). Just keep in mind even without using visual studio project you can easily create item templates. It's just a zip file containing mentioned files.

Comment: To find more information on how to create item templates and project templates and substitute parameters and other related stuffs, take a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019).

Comment: You can close all open .cs files then when you build it will not show any error. The intelliSense errors are not important and you can ignore them. To do so, in the `Error List` window, choose to show just build errors (from dropdown).

Comment: one more question, when I try to export the item template it's gives me only one cs to select, how can I take all the folder as an item?

Comment: The approach which I used is not exporting item templates. It's *Item template Project*. It means when you build the project, you will have the template zip file in bin/debug folder. - Or as an alternative, you can create the zip file yourself. Export item template is a different solution.

Comment: got it, tnx one more time. you have been very helpful

Comment: Cool! No problem :)

Comment: one more quasion i have class A intrerface for IA and class AB that need to implement IA in your example its building implemintation of IAB that not exist what can i do to map it to other class, and not his base AB

Comment: I assume `B` is a constant value like `Business`, if you create this entry in .vstemplate: `<ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$Business.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Business.cs</ProjectItem>` And have an `Business.cs` file with contents: `...class $safeitemrootname$: I$basename$ ...`, then when adding `Item1`, it will create `Item1Business.cs` which contains `...class Item1Business:IItem1...`. (By the way, I haven't tried that, but I'm pretty sure you can make a good use of $basename$ to achive what you want).

Comment: In general, the `$basename$` that I've defined in `.vstemplate` will transforms to the name which you select in dialog box. For example `Item1`.